# Set Kubernetes Readiness for elasticsearch client

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, livenessprobe

I upgraded the elasticsearch chart in kubernetes from 6.6 to 7.10.2 version. Data and master pods are running and ready but, the clients aren't ready (2 clients, 2 data , 3 master).

This is their status:

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE

    elasticsearch-client-685c875bb5-5mcxg   0/1     Running   0          2m23s
    elasticsearch-client-685c875bb5-cs9lq   0/1     Running     0          24m
```

When I run describe I see this warning:

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  10s (x10 over 100s)  kubelet,  Readiness probe failed: Get http://_cluster/health: net/http: request canceled (Client. Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

and in kubectl logs, I get this

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-01-24T13:43:41,318Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "r.suppressed", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-client-685c875bb5-5mcxg", "message": "path: /_cluster/health, params: {}",
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: null",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:230) [elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:335) [elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:252) [elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:601) [elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:684) [elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]"] }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-01-24T13:43:51,319Z", "level": "WARN", "component": "r.suppressed", "cluster.name": "elasticsearch", "node.name": "elasticsearch-client-685c875bb5-5mcxg", "message": "path: /_cluster/health, params: {}",
"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: null",
"at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.onTimeout(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:230) [elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ContextPreservingListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:335) [elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:252) [elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterApplierService$NotifyTimeout.run(ClusterApplierService.java:601) [elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
"at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:684) [elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) [?:?]",
"at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) [?:?]",
"at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]"] }
```

I set the readiness and liveness initialDelaySeconds to 90
what might be the problem here?

Comment: It's not a good idea to jump from version 6.6 to 7.10 directly, Try upgrading to 6.6-->6.8, then 6.8-->7.10. [Recommendation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html)

Comment: Could you also please `kubectl describe` your elasticsearch services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have upgraded from 6.x to 7.x, make sure that you have set `cluster.initial_master_nodes` in your `env` or in the `elasticsearch.yml` config file.

Answer (score 0):

You must have odd number of master nodes, e.g. 1, 3, 5 and so on, usually 3 masters is optimal. Otherwise your cluster won't work due to lack of [quorum](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-quorums.html).

Comment: thanks I set 3 but still get the same any other suggestions?

Comment: you should see your master pods logs and dig why the quorum is not forming.

Comment: I agree with Vasili Angapov. Can you provide logs from elasticsearch `Pods` ?